# jquery if else statements both executing in sequence

Tags: jquery, if-statement

I'm working on a mobile nav. There must be something fundamentally wrong about my understanding of how a simple if/else works (and I haven't been working with jQ/js for a while), as both statements are executing, in series. Actually the 'else' runs first, then - whether or not I include the 'toggleNav()' function or $(nav).toggleClass('open') - then the 'if' statement also executes.

I thought this might be event-related so I've tried the function on both the li.dashboard-toggle-nav and the link within (a.dashboard-toggle-nav-link), with the same results; also I've tried qualifying the if/else using length method and checking for visibility (having spent some time reading related questions here on SO); still, the 'else' statement executes, then the 'if'.

Btw, the undesired result was only occurring on my laptop (FF & Chrome) but worked as intended on my testing android (also FF & Chrome). Can someone please explain to me why this is happening?

I realize there are other ways to toggle visibility or display of an element but I was under the impression that, at least in an example like this, simply toggling class was appropriate,

Thanks

Whiskey T.

HTML:

```
<li class="dashboard-tool dashboard-toggle-nav">
    <a class="dashboard-toggle-nav-link" href="#" title="Show Menu">Menu</a>
</li>
<nav id="nav"> ... etc.
```

jQ:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".dashboard-toggle-nav").on("click", ".dashboard-toggle-nav-link", function(e) {
        var nav = $("nav#nav"); // <nav#nav> holds both #nav-search + ul#nav-catalog

        // same problem using: if (($("nav.open").length == 0)) {
        // same problem using: if ($(nav).is(":visible")) {
        if ($(nav).hasClass("open")) {
            alert(" *if* ");
            $(nav).slideUp(333);
        }

        else {
            alert(" *else* ");
            $(nav).slideDown(666);
        }

        // problem occurs with or without this:
        // $(nav).toggleClass("open");
        // ... or this:
        toggleNav();
        e.preventDefault();
    })

    function toggleNav() {
        alert("toggleNav running");
        $(nav).toggleClass("open");
    }

});
```

Comment: are you saying you get the `*else*` alert before also getting the `*if*` alert?

Comment: use console.log() instead of alert() so you can see the timing and order of events.

Comment: Do you realize that `.slideUp()` and `.slideDown()` are asynchronous?  Calling them only starts their operation and then they continue in the background while the rest of your Javascript continues to run.

Comment: @Jamiec Yes, the 'else' runs first, because on load the nav is not displayed, does not have '.open' class

Comment: Then didnt you just answer your own question?

Comment: @devlincarnate I do normally use console.log, but reverted to alerts 'cause I was testing on the phone. I'll update with console.log and update shortly. Thanks

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks, but my problem is that else runs, then toggleNav, so the class is added, but why then does the entire function continue to run, i.e., then the 'if' is true so the nav is re-hidden (all on a single click event)?

Comment: @devlincarnate FWIW, console reads: *else* , toggleNav running, *if*, toggleNav running

Comment: try using `e.stopImmediatePropagation();` after e.preventDefault();

Comment: @devlincarnate Thank you! This works, though I'm still trying to understand what's wrong with my understanding of an if/else; on click, only one of the conditions is true, so why does the function apparently test again and find the other condition true (which it is then, of course) and then immediately close the nav (unless I include the stopImmediatePropagation() method, that is). Many thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function is running twice (which is evident from your console log results).  The first time, it takes the falsey path and the second time, it's taking the truthy path because of the actions taken in the first pass.

preventDefault stops the default action of the click event, but it doesn't stop the event from further propagating up the DOM.  [stopImmediatePropagation()](http://fuelyourcoding.com/jquery-events-stop-misusing-return-false/) stops that propagation.

Comment: Thanks for the link. I read it and the Zakas article linked therein. My incorrect assumption was that using the .on method restricts the event to the '.dashboard-toggle-nav-link'. Out of curiosity, I tried removing the <a> from the list item and changing the click event accordingly (but w/out stopping the propagation), and still the function apparently runs twice; so why not more than twice, if it's seemingly bubbling up the DOM beyond the <li>? I'm amazed I haven't previously encountered propagation-related problems using simple functions. Thanks again.

Comment: p.s. I tried to upvote your answer but I don't yet have the points

Comment: @WhiskeyT.Foxtrot  yes, SO requires a certain level of rep to upvote.  However, if my answer solved your problem, you can you the checkmark to mark it as the solution.

Comment: @WhiskeyT.Foxtrot - it's hard to say.  you could try tracking the propagation.  I set up a [simple demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/hbx7cjds/) using [this script](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaScript/jQuery/Trackingeventpropagationwithbubbleandcapturehandlers.htm).